# AWS Elastic Beanstalk https setup for website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website written in AngularJs which send api request to another server application. If I want user to connect website through https, do I have to make server https also? I have already requested a ssl certificate on AWS with my website address, and applied it on the load balancer of website instance (not server instance). Do I have to request another certificate for my api server?

Thanks.

Comment: You can, but you don't "have" to. The question is, what is your goal? Do you just care that users see a green lock bar when they visit your website, or do you care that all data is very very super-extra secure

Comment: I want frontend website to show the secured icon. I tried adding ssl certificate on website instance, but it will return `no-referrer-when-downgrade` error.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that the communication between the client and server happens over https, especially if private data is being transmitted, such as login data.

Regarding certificates, in order to https to work, the common name (CN) that is used in the certificate must match the fully qualified domain of your server's URL. So yes, you need a new certificate created specifically for your back-end server.